# Express js / mongoose - How to catch SyntaxError from bad JSON request from API?

Tags: json, express, mongoose, error-handling

My express js / mongoose node application currently crashes when receiving bad / wrongly formatted JSON over the API. How can I catch this error in express js?

The error can be demonstrated by adding a route with minimal code, and then sending any badly formatted json to the express api (using Postman or a similar program).

```
  private routeTest() {
    this.router.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
      console.log('testing')
        res.sendStatus(204);
        next();
    }
  )}
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 19
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\dev\nddb\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\dev\nddb\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\dev\nddb\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\dev\nddb\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\dev\nddb\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

This can be solved by passing a custom error handler to Express js.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      if (err instanceof SyntaxError) return res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({
          error: "Invalid JSON"
      }))
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send();
    });
```